# What is the past tense of "would like to"?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

Could you tell me what the **past** tense of "would like to do" is? Is it "wanted to do"?

Also, I'd like to know the **present** and **past** perfect tense of "would like to do" if it has.

If it is not too much trouble, please give me a few example sentences for reference.

Comment: _Would_ is a modal auxiliary verb, and therefore is not inflected for tense. So it doesn't have a present or a past tense. And since it's a modal, it has to be first in a verb phrase and therefore can't occur after the _have_ of the perfect construction. So there really aren't any other forms to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The past of *would like to* is *would have liked to* or *would like to have [verb]*

For example:

**I would like to go skiing this weekend.**

vs.

**I would have liked *to go* skiing this weekend, but I have to go into work on Saturday**

or

**I would like *to have gone* skiing this weekend...**

Each of these forms is common usage.

Answer (score 0):

Morphologically, "would" is past tense (and grammatically, it serves as the past tense of "will").  In practice, it is used as though it were both present tense and past tense:

- PRESENT: I would like a cup of tea.
- PAST: I said that I would like a cup of tea. (*Cf* I said that I wanted...)
- PAST: I wondered whether he would like a cup of tea. (*Cf* I wondered whether he wanted...)
- PAST: I knew that she would like a cup of tea. (*Cf* I knew that she wanted...)

For certain purposes, a perfect construction is used to discuss the past:

- PERFECT: Yesterday I would have liked a cup of tea.

But note that whereas "Yesterday I wanted a cup of tea" doesn't indicate whether or not you obtained one, "Yesterday I would have liked a cup of tea" implies that you didn't get one.  There is therefore no straightforward past-tense equivalent of "I would like a cup of tea" ("Yesterday I would like a cup of tea" doesn't work, and "Yesterday I would have liked..." alters the meaning).